# Real World ASP.NET MVC Applications with Source Code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I think all of the tutorials and stuff are great on blogs, but sometimes when you actually build an application the way you would code or interact with a system is quite different.

I was wondering if you all knew some good real world type ASP.NET MVC applications that have the source code available for experimentation.

Off hand I am aware of the following, but I'm interested to see if there are more:

- [Flickr Xplorer ASP.NET MVC website using jQuery](http://www.codeplex.com/FlickrXplorer/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=18041) ([live website](http://www.flickrmvc.net/Photo/intel#259803598))
- [Kigg](http://www.codeplex.com/Kigg) ([live website](http://kigg.dotnetslackers.com/))
- [Forums: Create the Perfect Application](http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/2008/09/05/asp-net-mvc-application-building-forums-1-create-the-perfect-application.aspx)
- [MVC Storefront](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/) (thanks to [cristianlibardo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16526/cristianlibardo) for reminding me of this one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you know of [storefront](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/). I've heard it's a good tutorial and it comes with source code.

Comment: Ohh yeah, I forgot about that one. I knew I was forgetting something. Any others?

Comment: [here](https://mvcsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/18861) is the codeplex link for MVC storefront

Answer (score 1):

### Oxite

Oxite is a **simple blog engine written using ASP.NET MVC**, and is designed with two main goals:

1. To provide a sample of 'core blog functionality' in a reusable fashion. Blogs are simple and well understood by many developers, but the set of basic functions that a blog needs to implement (trackbacks, rss, comments, etc.) are fairly complex. Hopefully this code helps.
2. To provide a real-world sample written using ASP.NET MVC.

**Links**

- [Oxite Website on VisitMix](http://visitmix.com/Lab/Oxite)
- [Oxite on CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/oxite)

Update: Karl Seguin critizing the Oxite implementation: http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2008/12/15/oxite-oh-dear-lord-why.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I learnt using [NOPCommerce](http://nopcommerce.com). It showcases pretty much every feature of ASP.NET MVC and the latest version is on MVC5.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Code Plex](http://www.codeplex.com/Project/ProjectDirectory.aspx?TagName=MVC)

Answer (score 0):

[NuGet sources](http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) include the server project to run nuget.org.