# Real winforms/wpf projects which use MVC, MVP, MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, mvvm, mvp

I have looked some videos and read some articles about **MVC, MVP, MVVM.** I think, that I understood basic principles and differences.  But it seems to me that samples in articles and videos are very easy.

I think that it's easy to learn how to apply these patterns when you can look on some projects.

So I'd like to look on real projects(**Winforms/WPF**), which use **MVC, MVP** or **MVVM**. Could you provide me links to sources of such projects? (If it is open source)

It will be great if projects will have unit tests for Controller/Presenter/ViewModel, because it's one of my problem when I develop applications.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

CodePlex will have a fair few http://www.codeplex.com/

I assume you have also used the samples at http://www.asp.net/mvc (you seemed to suggest this in your post)

Edit: also see these questions:
[Good examples of WPF applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534328/good-example-wpf-applications)

[Real World ASP.NET MVC Applications with Source Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198482/real-world-asp-net-mvc-applications-with-source-code)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I already looked to http://www.asp.net/mvc, and it was very useful for me for developing asp.net apps. Thanks very much for link to "Good example WPF applications".

Answer (score 0):

Mini SQL Query at codeplex http://minisqlquery.codeplex.com/

see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25376174/423356