# Sample MVC / MVP winforms Application (Non Trivial)

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, mvp

I'm looking for a non-trivial example of MVC/MVP implemented in Winforms (C# .NET).  I searched the website but getting only trivial examples, a little more would be helpful.

I'm Particularly looking at ways to implement views (view for a master-child model) and controllers/presenters.

Comment: Which websites did you search? Codeplex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project covers a lot more than just the forms - it demonstrates CQRS and EventSourcing amongst others, but also uses MVP (Simple View type) for it's UI:

It is designed to be a demo application and there is a lot of information in his blog about it too (links in his readme.txt on gitHub.)

[Fohjin by Mark Nijof](http://github.com/MarkNijhof/Fohjin/)

Answer (score 3):

I was working on windows form project (the project is using third party winform library not compatile with wpf) and searching for mvp best practice for winform; I found Mini SQL Query at codeplex:
http://minisqlquery.codeplex.com/

this covers winform, mvp, dependency injection with castle windsor, weifen luo docking suite, command pattern, etc

so far this is best real working winform mvp sample for me(not too complex once you know how the components interconnected)

ps: the castle library used is version 2.5 so if you upgrade to version 3 this project won't compile

[image: application screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for answering this question after 4 years... I appreciate your commitment. Will look into the sample.

Comment: hehe I was having difficulty looking for non trivial sample myself and got to your post, Just want to share with others (who uses same search keywords like mine :) ).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at **Koossery.MVCWin**.  It has links to some tutorials that should provide some sample applications.  In addition, it's an actual MVC framework, so it might help you get there faster.

http://koosserymvcwin.codeplex.com/

Also have a look at **MVCSharp**.

http://mvcsharp.org/