# ASP.Net MVC real world-level sample business applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I need to re-write a businesss InfoPath / SharePoint application that has a fair bit of logic associated the operations a user performs - such as enable / disable controls; show / hide controls (complex tab controls); retrieve different data nad display differenty - as determined by user activity.

In trying to decide whether to use ASP.Net Web forms or ASP.Net MVC. As such I have been hunting around for a good realworld ASP.Net MVC sample business application (with Source code).

Does anyone know of anything that can demonstrate to me how to achieve the 'richness' of user interactions and responses in ASP.Net MVC that one can achieve using Web Forms?

I am know the Dinner Nerd application; and have checked out the offerings on CodePlex. So far most of the sample applications I have found do not have much of the complexity we have become used to dealing with in Web forms; and that I need to try and achieve. I posiibly have have to rethink the presentation & flow of the application in response to user actions in an MVC application (as compared to how one migh structure the flow in  InfoPath / Winforms and Web forms). This might shift me more to what the existing sample applications might be indicating to me -'change the focus of the Views to be of presentational bias'. As such one would end up with many views each only permitting a reduced set of use interactions.

Thanks for any comments in advance.

Grant

Comment: possible duplicate of [Real World ASP.NET MVC Applications with Source Code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198482/real-world-asp-net-mvc-applications-with-source-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is exactly the same question asked here (ok, it is not about business apps) - [Real World ASP.NET MVC Applications with Source Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198482/real-world-asp-net-mvc-applications-with-source-code)

just keep in mind that asp.net-mvc makes it really easy to write unit tests, which is the most important thing when coding applications.

If you have complex interaction scenarios you might be interested in performance too, asp-net.mvc performance is a way better...

Asp.net-mvc 2 (I haven't looked at 3 yet) makes the validation really easy and you can choose at which level you want it.

Comment: Svetlozar. Thanks for your reply and pointing out the other post. I agree totally with you re-testability. As far as the sample applications I have checked all of the ones that are available and still find them 'light weight' in terms of what I might need to achieve in the business application we envisage. Interestingly, a number of the sample applications do not appear to have progressed much. Some have moved to CodePlex and downloads are not available.

I will keep hunting.